# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IList to Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IList

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

This is the piece of code where I'm getting an error in the results area. I am new to MVC. Could you please help me?

```
IList<DownloadFileVM> DownloadFile = new List<DownloadFileVM>();
IList<DownloadFileDto> result = _downloadFileService.GetDownloadDetails(User.OrganisationId,true);
DownloadFile = Mapper.Map<IList<DownloadFileVM>, IList<DownloadFileDto>>(result);
return View("DownloadFile", DownloadFile);
```

Error shown is:

> Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from

```
 System.Collections.Generic.IList<DomainLogic.DTOs.DownloadFileDto>
```

> to

```
 System.Collections.Generic.IList<FileUploadPortal.Models.DownloadFileVM>
```

Comment: Please show some respect to SO memebers, spend some time on code formatting and write several words describing your problem

Comment: No indication that you've actually created the mapping configuration either.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the order of AutoMapper mapping function generic parameters:

```
Mapper.Map<IList<DownloadFileDto>, IList<DownloadFileVM>>(result);
```

First generic parameter is the type of source object, and second parameter is type of destination object (which you are trying to get from source). Also you can specify only destination type, because source type can be inferred from method argument:

```
Mapper.Map<IList<DownloadFileVM>>(result);
```

NOTE: You don't need to initialize `DownloadFile` with empty list. You can declare and assign that variable in one place:

```
IList<DownloadFileVM> DownloadFile = Mapper.Map<IList<DownloadFileVM>>(result);
```